# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split' keeps recurring when I tried to install jupyter notebook

Tags: android, jupyter, terminal-emulator, pydroid

[The error is relined out...maybe aan up parsing issue?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QasPJ.jpg)

What should I do in terminal emulator to solve the issue? I want to install jupyter on my Android and I tried several times on pydroid but always got stuck in this error...

BTW... my device is running Android 10
And I have tried to install jupyter onto my another Android device which is running Oreo and it works! Does that mean there's anything pertaining to the system build issues?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is because the default ip is set as `localhost` which android has problem parsing.

Opening the notebook with a set ip address fixed this issue for me.

Try opening a notebook with the ip option

```
jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0
```